# How to add a <legend> within a <table>

Tags: html, forms, html-table, legend, fieldset

At the moment I have:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Info</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Info</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

But the legend title 'Personal Info' appears above the line and NOT in the middle of the line.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I get this instead:

**__________Personal Info__________**

Comment: What do you mean "middle of the line" ? Are you saying you don't want it like this - http://jsfiddle.net/nischaalc/meagux14/?

Comment: I do want it like that, but it doesn't display like that. Instead the text is above the line not within it.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am currently using Firefox 31.0

Comment: That's really strange... Have you tested it with other browsers?

Comment: Yes, both on IE and Chrome its the same

Answer (score 0):

Apply a style to your legend tag e.g.

```
<legend style="position:absolute; left:50%;">Personal Info</legend>
```

Comment: I did not checked it with every browser, but works on Firefox.

Comment: I am currently using Firefox 31.0

Comment: Maybe the old page is still in the cache? I am using the same Version and the caption is displayed within the border.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! :) I just had to adjust the height on the  maybe due to me using twitter bootstrap there was some conflict with the bootstrap css styles for the  property.